# gethostname() in windows

Tags: c++, winsock

I've found out that the gethostname() function returns the standard host name for the local computer, but I am a little confused about the term "host name",is it the name of the computer at which the function is being called or the name of the server with which the computer is connected in a network...

```
          char szPath[128] = "";
          gethostname(szPath, sizeof(szPath));
```

also what shoud I do if I want to find out the ip address of the local host...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gethostname : returns local computer name.

To get IP address, use:

```
   struct hostent *ent = gethostbyname(hostname);
   struct in_addr ip_addr = *(struct in_addr *)(ent->h_addr);
   printf("Hostname: %s, was resolved to: %s\n",
           hostname, inet_ntoa(ip_addr));
```

Comment: one more thing,the name returned by the "gethostname" function,I am again confused,is it the mac addressof the machine???

Comment: @Aayman Khalid, most welcome :) Well, it is not mac-addr, it is the computer-name.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms738527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The `gethostname` function retrieves the standard host name **for the local computer**.